# Can you help with a contex-free grammar for the language 0^n 1^m 2^k where n+ 2k >= m?

Tags: formal-grammars

Can you help with a contex-free grammar for the language 0^n 1^m 2^k where n + 2k >= m?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove that a language is context-free?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The language is the same as $0^i 0^n 1^n (11)^k 2^k 2^j$. If I made no mistakes. Which is up to you to check. And yes, there’s a tiny mistake.